# How can I install Publify (Typo) on an existing site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, publify

How can I install [Publify](https://github.com/publify/publify) on an existing rails app in the subdirectory /blog? I am running rails 3.2. Can anyone help? Or at least point me in the right direction? Thanks!

A similar question was asked, but never answered [here](https://github.com/publify/publify).

Answer (score 2):

Before following below steps you should know there will be two applications: your main application and publify application. So both should run on different ports.

1. Download source code from https://github.com/publify/publify. Follow the guide and run this application. It is very easy to run and install, everything is mentioned clearly. If any error you got while installation, post the error.
2. Run publify application to some port let us say localhost:3000
3. Let us say you have your main application which runs at localhost:4000

   In your views just write this script which will rediret you from your main application to publify running at localhost:3000 by link_to method.

Now you can use publify.